# Storage plugin configuration on Zookeeper for Apache Drill + Zookeeper in Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, apache-zookeeper, apache-drill

I am running Apache Drill and Zookeeper on a Kubernetes cluster.

Drill is connecting to zookeeper through a zookeeper-service running on port 2181. I am trying the persist storage plugin configuration on zookeeper. On the Apache Drill docs (https://drill.apache.org/docs/persistent-configuration-storage/), it is given that sys.store.provider.zk.blobroot key needs to be added to drill-override.conf property. But I am not able to figure out a value for this key if I want to connect it to Zookeeper service in Kubernetes.

Answer (score 2):

The value should be:

```
<name-of-your-zk-service>.<namespace-where-zk-is-running>.svc.cluster.local:2181
```

That's how services get resolved internally in Kubernetes. You can always test it by creating a Pod, connecting to is using `kubectl exec -it <pod-name> sh`, and running:

```
ping <name-of-your-zk-service>.<namespace-where-zk-is-running>.svc.cluster.local
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is an optional config. You can specify it to modify where the ZooKeeper PStore provider offloads query profile data [1] or you can remove this property from your `drill-override.conf` and restart drillbits.

[1] http://doc.mapr.com/display/MapR/Persistent+Configuration+Storage